# How to insert a value to postgres database column which contains double quotes and triple quotes

Tags: postgresql, django-models, postgresql-9.3

I want to insert a query string into a Postgres database column in the following format

```
{"enrolled_time":'''SELECT DISTINCT enrolled_time AT TIME ZONE %s FROM alluser'''}
```

I try this:

```
UPDATE reports SET raw_query = {"enrolled_time":'''SELECT DISTINCT enrolled_time AT TIME ZONE %s FROM alluser'''}  WHERE id=37;
```

It gives error like

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 1: UPDATE base_reports SET extra_query = {"enrolled_time":'''SE...
```

When I try using single quotes it throws error like following:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 1: ...DATE reports SET raw_query = '{"enrolled_time":'''SELECT DIS...
```

How can I overcome this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING):

```
UPDATE reports
SET raw_query = $${"enrolled_time":'''SELECT DISTINCT enrolled_time AT TIME ZONE %s FROM alluser'''}$$
WHERE id = 37;
```